# Listview below listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to have a listview containing some content. And below it, when you scroll to the buttom of the listview, a new header would be displayed followed with a new list view. Is is possible?

//Edit
The two listview need to have differet layout xml.

Have tried to put the second listview in a the footview of the first. But then the second listview is to small.

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:background="@drawable/app_topbar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView android:text="@string/headline_notused"
                android:gravity="center" android:textSize="24sp" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/txtcolor" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:visibility="gone" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:id="@+id/progressbarHorizontal" />

        <ListView android:id="@+id/notUsedList" android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressbarHorizontal"></ListView>

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/notUsedList" android:background="@drawable/app_background"
            android:layout_marginBottom="55dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myUsedHeader"
                android:background="@drawable/app_topbar" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                <TextView android:text="@string/headline_used" android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/txtcolor"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView android:id="@+id/usedList"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="5dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You set the layout for the list and the list items when you init the adapter. I don't understand the issue... your first list has nothing to do with the second except to tell it when it reaches the last list item.

Comment: I don't understand your ned: do you want to replace your listview with a new one or make your previous listview longer by adding some items with different row layout?

Comment: make my previous listview longer by adding some items with different row layout. I also need to add a new header. Sorry if it is difficult to understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean listview with different sections and each  sections having a header. Try this link [Jeff sharkey adapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)

Comment: Is it possible to change layout, so the two listview runs different layouts?

Comment: You mean rows of both listview should have different layout. Sure that is can be done.

Comment: I got this working, one place I need it, so it was awesome. But in another activity I also needed to change the background behind the listview. Here i ended up with putting the second listview in the footerview of the first, and then i code behinde calculting the hight of 1 item * arraylist.size() into dp, and it also worked. So thanks for the repleys.

Answer (score 1):

You should detect when you arrive at the listview last item.

Then, you can change your adapter, change activity or wathever you find appropriate to display the new ListView:

Implement an `OnScrollListener`, set your `ListView`'s `onScrollListener` and then you should be able to handle things correctly.

For example:

```
// Initialization stuff.
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(this);

// ... ... ...

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView lw, final int firstVisibleItem,
                 final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {

    switch(lw.getId()) {
        case android.R.id.list:     

            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                // Last item is fully visible. You will then need to start a New activity, maybe... Or change the layout.. I don't know!
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, and is it possible to change the layout xml also?

Comment: Yeah of course, you will just have to change your Adapter. I don't know your application, but personnally, I would start a new Activity with a new Listview... But if your need is to stay in the same activity, just do something like: getListView().setAdapter(new YourAdapter(blabla));

Comment: This example was nice. It helped me load new stuff into my listview, when button was hit. So thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. you can define one listview in linearlayout and onether in other linearlayout and put both in parent LinearLayout.

Comment: It needs to be linearlayout? Because I got a scrollproblem right now. I'm also trying to put the last listview inside the footview to the first, but it dosn't work.

Comment: android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" use this in property of listview  it'll solve scrollview problem.